# How can i get to models to run in Openmodelica

Tags: openmodelica

I am currently trying to learn Openmodelica with the buildings library , since I need to use that for my project.

I am trying to run an example model by duplicating it into a new package. The model runs when it is within the Buildings library, but when i duplicate it into a new package it crashes and shows the below error:

"Process crashed Simulation process failed. Exited with code 0xffffffffc0000005."

Using OpenModelica v1.20.0 (64-bit) for my simulations. Would be great if someone can help

The model runs when it is within the Buildings library, but when i duplicate it into a new package it crashes

Comment: Probably the model depends on some external C libraries which are not duplicated when you create your new model. You need to read and learn about resources in Modelica.